# How to point domain name into an IP address (ubuntu server)?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name

I have one ubuntu server running in a specific ip address. Multiple apps are running with the help of gunicorn and nginx. I can access all those apps after editing the '/etc/hosts' file in my local machine.

Then, I bought a domain name. Now, the problem I'm having is to point my domain name to my ip address of the server.

I contacted the domain provider but they told me 'for custom name server you need to contact your hosting provider to point A record on your branded name server'. This went over my head, as I'm not familiar with these.

I researched a bit and found the use of 'BIND' but I'm not 100% sure. I don't want to end up breaking my server. So, what do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get a domain they just register it for you. But it won't activate unless few DNS records are published to the internet, informing about its existence. A DNS server has to be there to announce those records and enable you to define sub-domains under it.

Either you run that name server yourself, OR you have to buy a hosting space, by which you get a name server you can add records to. Providers usually try to sell you the second option. BIND is one of name server programs you may run on your server to do the job. This is a bit technical and is not suggested unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: I assumed DNS records are provided after domain is registered and it can be edited. I didn't know that I had to buy the hosting space to be able to edit the DNS records. Job done. Thanks.